# Log Custom Destination and Log Archival support for Binary Files

Tags: logging

Are Custom Destination and Log Archival supported for Binary files like TRC files (audit files) of Microsoft SQL Server?

IHAC that is unable to view the TRC files in Log Explorer, and they would like to forward these logs to an S3 bucket.

Comment: Please red https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask